# SQL - Return distinct hours between two periods

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, distinct

I've got the following piece of SQL which is returning all the distinct days between the two dates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(char(10), date, 120) as StartDate from table1 WHERE  
id = @id and date > @StartDate
```

However I need to return the distinct dates and hours between the two dates.

I.e.

> 2011-12-18 13:00:00.000
>
> 2011-12-18 14:00:00.000
>
> 2011-12-18 17:00:00.000
>
> 2011-12-19 10:00:00.000
>
> 2011-12-19 12:00:00.000
>
> 2011-12-19 13:00:00.000

Was hoping someone may be able to assist on altering the query to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(HH,DATEDIFF(HH,0,DATE),0) as StartDate 
from table1 
WHERE   id = @id and date > @StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT left(convert(varchar, date, 120), 13) as starthour
from table
WHERE   id = @id and date > @StartDate
```

You could also come up with something similar using the datepart() function in SQL Server.  In other databases, it would be better to use extract( from ).

Comment: `DATEADD` is much more efficient than string conversion. I also highly, highly recommend never specifying `varchar` without specifying a length. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx

Comment: Why would you use DATEADD?  I mentioned DATEPART.  It is not clear to me that repeated calls to DATEPART are more efficient than one conversion to a string followed by a simple string manipulation.  As for the varchar without a length, I plead guilty.  I just don't put the length into the convert() function for a couple of reasons.  (1) Laziness.  (2) I might get the length wrong for the format.

Comment: Regardless of whether it is clear to you, datetime conversions are more efficient than string conversions, especially if you have to convert back to datetime (or append the `':00:00'` to every row in the result to make it look like you did). It also allows you to not care about the various style numbers. And in this case you know the length is 13 because you're wrapping it in a `LEFT()` function. So you could avoid the `LEFT` in the first place if you used `CHAR(13)` instead of `varchar(unspecified)`.

Comment: This might be worthwhile reading. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @myDates table(d datetime);
INSERT INTO @myDates VALUES('2011-12-18 13:00:00.000')
, ('2011-12-18 14:00:00.000')
, ('2011-12-18 17:00:00.000')
, ('2011-12-19 10:00:00.000')
, ('2011-12-19 12:00:00.000')
, ('2011-12-19 13:00:00.000');

; WITH a AS (
    SELECT d, r=ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY d)
    FROM @myDates
)
SELECT StartDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.d,120)
, EndDate=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a2.d,120)
, HoursDiff=DATEDIFF(hh,a1.d,a2.d)
FROM a a1
INNER JOIN a a2 
  ON a2.r=a1.r+1 
  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a1.d,120)<>CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),a2.d,120);
```

Result:

```
StartDate  EndDate    HoursDiff
---------- ---------- -----------
2011-12-18 2011-12-19 17
```